# Using TapGestureRecognizer over profileimage in TableViewController (wrong indexPath)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

Good morning,

I'm going to update my post because I need your help (I'm out of solutions) with my problem using the TapGestureRecognizer.

That's my Segue code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueprofile"]) {

        OtherProfileUserViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSLog(@"jsonArray ==> %@", [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"id"]);

        destViewController.recipeName = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"id"];
    }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueprofile2"]) {

        OtherProfileUserViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSLog(@"jsonArray ==> %@", [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"id"]);

        destViewController.recipeName = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"id"];
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
    {
        CarDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSLog(@"jsonArray ==> %@", [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"id"]);

        detailViewController.carDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                               initWithObjects:
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"date"],
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"id"],
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"imagen"],
                                               nil];
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have some outputs to check the ID of the user selected, but it's not working on the firsts two cases (I have always the same ID) but in the last one everything is working fine (and I think it's because the "SELECTION" of the CUSTOM ROW.

What I have to do in order to make the other two segues work with the correct information? I have connected my imageView (first segue) to a TapGestureRecognizer and this to a Segue action, the second is the same but from a UILabel.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: i think you have place reload tableview on wrong place.

Comment: Where I have to put the reload TableView? Thanks @AshokLondhe

Comment: I think you place it in cellForRowAtIndexPath and try it.

Comment: have you tried it or not.

Comment: Not yet @AshokLondhe, I'm going to try it in the evening because I'm away from my MAC. Thanks.

Comment: k. inform me after solving your problem.

Comment: It didn't work @AshokLondhe. I have updated my first message with more information regarding the problem, I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. But i require some time.

Comment: I will be much appreciated if you can help me because I'm stuck in this problem for more than one week and I'm out of solutions...! I have tried too many times without succeed.

Comment: Just See my answer and try...if not solve inform me.

Comment: i think you are not selecting Cell. You are selecting image of that cell right...

Comment: I have updated my first message in order to show you my Segue code, because there is something not working there. Please help me if you can @AshokLondhe

Answer (score 0):

If you read UITableview's documentation. The **indexPathForSelectedRow** method returns an index path identifying the row and section of the selected row, like button's clicked and table cell selection event two different things. Like button click will not update selected row and selected section of tableview. There are multiple ways to resolve your problem. I am giving you one of simple solution.

First create weak outlet property to Like button (if you don't have) in CarTableViewCell.h file, and connect it.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *likeButton;
```

Then, update button tag in method

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)anIndexPath
    {
        self.selectedIndexPath = anIndexPath;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

        CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
    cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    //I skiped your code.........
    }
```

Final step, use tag for cell row index in button event.

```
- (IBAction)plusOne:(UIButton *)sender {
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)sender.tag);
}
```

Comment: @BBangF1 did you try my solution ?

Comment: Yes, I tried yesterday but it's returning 0 always. I'm going to update my first message because I'm using a Segue on my "user profile image", which is going to show a "ProfileViewController" with the username sent, but again, that value is not updated when I touch another image from another row.

Comment: Can you check my first post again, please? I need some advice with my code from the Segue part. Thanks @bhavesh

Answer (score 0):

I have faced your problem before,

I solved it as the following:

give the cell a value for its tag property. Then get the cell:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:tagValue];
```

then get the NSIndexPath like this

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell: cell];
```

hope it will help:)

Comment: Where I have to put that code? I'm a littlr bit lost. Thanks @user2168496

Comment: Can you check again my first post, please? I need some help with my problem. Thanks again @user2168496

Answer (score 0):

Please write this code in viewWillAppear method instead of viewDidLoad

```
[self fetchJson];

[self.tableView reloadData];

// Initialize the refresh control.
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
//self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(fetchJson)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Tell me after solving Problem.

Comment: It didn't work, when I press the imageView it still shows the latest userProfile and not the current one I pressed. Maybe you want me to show you my StoryBoard, can you help me please? Thanks in advance @AshokLondhe